# How can I use a particular emacs style?

Tags: emacs

How can I use [this emacs style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el) in my emacs?

And how can I format all my existing code using this style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the documentation embedded as comments in the linked file:

```
;; Provides the google C/C++ coding style. You may wish to add
;; `google-set-c-style' to your `c-mode-common-hook' after requiring this
;; file. For example:
;;
;;    (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style)
```

What this means is that you should copy the `google-c-style.el` file somewhere
Emasc will find it (in your `~/.emacs.d` directory, for example). Then add the
following lines in your init file:

```
(require 'google-c-style)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style)
```

---

As to formatting existing code using this style, in any given buffer you can use

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> : select the entire buffer contents
- <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> : indent the region

If you have a whole lot of open buffers, you can use `ibuffer` to automate
reindenting all of them:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ibuffer`<kbd>RET</kbd> : open the buffers list
- mark all buffers to be indented (for example using <kbd>m</kbd>)
- <kbd>E</kbd>`(indent-region (point-min) (point-max))`<kbd>RET</kbd> : reindent
  all marked buffers
- <kbd>S</kbd> : save all marked buffers if you are satisfied with the result